# Getting syntax error, but very unsure what is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a syntax error. When I check the the creation of each table by itself, the syntax is fine. When I do it together, it's not. Could you please help.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id         int(11)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,

     id             int(11)
                    NOT NULL,

    date_added      timestamp
                    NOT NULL
                    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE prod (
    prod_id         int(20)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,

    user_id         int(11)
                    NOT NULL,
                    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),

    info_str        varchar(1000)
                    NOT NULL,

    date_added      timestamp
                    NOT NULL
                    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

---

Error:

> Syntax error on line 15

Comment: This sql runs fine [in this MySQL 5.7 db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qy4m825c8GmCC32mCJ4jKK/0). How are you running this SQL code ? From PHP ? Please show us that part of the code.

Comment: Line 15 is the second `CREATE TABLE`, so I assume you are executing two statements through an interface that only allows you to execute one statement at a time. Most APIs do NOT support multi-query, and that's fine, there's really no benefit to using multi-query. Just execute one statement at a time.

Comment: @GMB No, I paste the code in phpmyadmin's sql code code and click go. There's no PHP code that I wrote?

Comment: @BillKarwin I just paste all the code in an interface and press go.

Comment: Although I am unsure, you could see if the following helps:

Replace semi-colon with / and execute both the statements together.


Create table users...
(
  ....
)

/

Create table...
(
 ....
)

/

Comment: I just pasted that code into my phpMyAdmin (MySQL 5.6) and it worked fine...